# Seems like every cool new website has an intro video. Where's the best place to host it?

Tags: video, hosting

Almost every new website seems to have an intro video that tells prospective new users about what the site's about and what it does.

What's the best way to host such a video?

I looked into the usual suspects, but each seems to have crippling flaws:

1. Youtube - Can stick ads into my
   video, making it look very
   amateurish
2. Vimeo - Expressly
   forbids commercial use
3. Self-hosting with JWPlayer - Cannot
   be re-embedded (I think), costs
   money. In regards to the
   re-embedding point, Techcrunch
   recently made the point that they
   and other news sites about tech love
   to embed those intro videos into
   their articles, and sites that have
   non-embeddable videos are giving up
   free coverage.

Edit: I'm not talking about the flash intros that must be clicked through to see the site, I'm referring to the optional videos users can click to learn more. Example: [Four Square](http://foursquare.com/) click More Info, [Hot Potato](http://hotpotato.com) click Video Tour on right, etc..

Also, I hate these videos as much as anyone, but recognize that end users love them. I fully intend to have a text and image version as an alternative for people like me that hate videos.

I don't see any consensus among these websites that I visit on the best way to host these videos. I'm hoping that people have recommendations other than the 3 I highlighted above already.

Comment: Please don't use an intro video... I always hate watching them.

Comment: "Almost every new website" are you sure those sites are as new as you think? Intro pages with videos/animations have come and gone. And hopefully they'll stay gone. :)

Comment: I don't think he's talking about stuff like flash intros. I think he's talking more about stuff like the Android 2.2 video on http://www.android.com

Comment: If there are lots of examples ("almost every new website"), then look through their scripts/check their watermarks and see what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI Rule #1: The more the user has to click, the worse the design is.

Ari's Corollary: Forcing a user to sit through an intro video counts.

Seriously, don't do this.  If you have to, youtube is probably the good route.

Answer (score 0):

Just host the file on some CDN (Amazon/Limelight/...) and then just embed it using whatever player you want (JWPlayer, slideshowpro)